# Displaying an warning Tooltip on Handsontable column by custom renderer

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

I have an instance of HandsonTable where I need to display an warning tooltip stating as required field. One cell of the table contains delete button and as soon as the table becomes empty(no rows having data) whether by delete button action or while the page load itself, I want to show a warning/alert tooltip.
I have made a custom renderer where right now I am able to display an image on the above mentioned conditions. But I am not able to apply the tooltip probably because tootltip is displayed on mouse hover. I need to render an element which directly shows the tooltip(without mouse hover) when the table is empty.